# Horizontal navigation with float and absolute positioning

Tags: css, position, horizontallist

I have a horizontal navbar in the form of an unordered list, where the list items are all floated left, and the list has `overflow:hidden;` for consistency. I want the "active" tab to be taller, without changing the layout of the list element.

The navbar is 60px tall with each list item 50px tall, and I want the active tab to be 55px. The question is, how do I get the list items to "stick" to the bottom of the navbar, without changing their horizontal positioning?

Things I've tried: (this list will grow)

- `ul#nav{position:relative;}` and `ul#nav li{position:absolute;bottom:0;}` stacks all elements on top of each other; I refuse to hard-code each tab's position
- `ul#nav li.active {position:relative;bottom:/* difference in heights */;}` leaves the block where the tab originally was empty, effectively acting as an unwanted margin

Comment: vertical-align:bottom will work if your <li< are set display:inline-block instead floatting:) http://dabblet.com/gist/5333194

Comment: @GCyrillus: thank you. I just found a solution though. I was already styling the `<li>/*anchor tags*/</li>` for border-width changes on the active tab, without shifting the elements (which involved changing padding), so I just extended this to the height and top margins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple (and I'd already been using it for styling of list items). Rather than style the list items themselves, I styled their contents, which are each anchor tags. So the default anchor tag has

```
height:50px;margin-top:10px;
```

while the `.active` tag is styled

```
height:55px;margin-top:5px;
```

A less difficult problem than I imagined.

Answer (score 0):

example with vertical-align : http://dabblet.com/gist/5333194

```
ul {
   line-height:60px;
}
    li {
        display:inline-block;
        vertical-align:bottom;
        height:50px;
    }
    li:hover {
        height:55px;
    }
```